# How to show last comments in php?

Tags: php

I have table with name "Comments", there is few columns: `ID, User, author, date, post`

What I want is to show last 10/20 comments, where newest is from top, all by vertically.

Comment: Can you please post your code

Comment: The question is not complete enough to really offer help. Where's your main problem, is it SQL or PHP related?

Answer (score 2):

That would be a database related question, ordering would normally be done inside an SQL query. Assuming you comments table has the given structure, it would be:

```
SELECT ID, user, author, date, post FROM Comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: I am not so good in php(good in css, html) So to show up in web site last comments i need to make :
<? echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT ID, user, author, date, post  TOP number column_name(s) * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10?>
this will be full code?

Comment: See above code fragment posted by @MevinBabu which should give you a sample to start with. I would recommend reading a bit about MySQL and PHP on [php.net](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php) to give you a basic idea how to use both.

Answer (score 1):

Append this to your sql statement `order by date desc limit 0,20`
That should give you the latest 20 comments

You could also add `OFFSET 20` if you want to show the next 20 results also.This can help you achieve the effect of loading the next page.

To show up comments you need to display them

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT ID, user, author, date, post TOP number column_name(s) * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
   echo $row[4];
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give him all records skipping the first 20 rows?

Comment: I am not so good in php(good in css, html) So to show up in web site last comments i need to make :
<? echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT ID, user, author, date, post  TOP number column_name(s) * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10?>
this will be full code?

Comment: @LeriKenchadze That code only displays the no. of rows to show the comments you should display them.I have edited the answer to accommodate it

Comment: Using [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://de3.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) and $row['post'] would be better otherwise changing column order or adding fields to your query may cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

Either `limit` in mysql query or jquery's `prepend()` would work.

Comment: I try this : 
<? echo ("SELECT ID, user, author, date, post FROM Comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10") ?>
and its shows just text :/ what im doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `order by id desc`. Once you fetch data from php, use jquery's `prepend()`.

Comment: `prepend()` will insert the comment at top of all the comments. Try some hands on twitter bootstrap also.

Comment: i managed this:
<? $q=mysql_query("SELECT id, user, author, date, post FROM Comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10");

while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
   echo $r['post'].'<br/>';
}
?>
Still comments didnt show up, wheres my error?

Comment: Have you tried to use `mysql_fetch_array()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP number column_name(s)
FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name(s) ASC|DESC
```

Comment: I am not so good in php(good in css, html) So to show up in web site last comments i need to make :
<? echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT ID, user, author, date, post  TOP number column_name(s) * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10?>
this will be full code?